# Dimensiones de las zonas de un BorderLayout

Tags: java

Tengo un problema en la interfaz que estoy desarrollando. Tengo 4 paneles (Oest, Center, East Y South) dentro de otro panel, el problema es que quiero modificar el tamaño del panel centro ya que es demasiado grande y esto disminuye el tamaño del panel derecho. ¿Cómo lo hago?

[image: Quisiera ensanchar el panel derecho a la marca azul]

Código del panel central (constructor):

public InformacionEstudianteLabel ()
    {

```
    TitledBorder borde = (new TitledBorder("Centro"));
    setBorder(borde);



    setLayout (new GridLayout (7,1));


    codigo = new JLabel ("Código:");
    nombres = new JLabel ("Nombres:");
    apellidos = new JLabel ("Apellidos:");
    semestreIngreso= new JLabel ("Semestre de ingreso:");
    facultad = new JLabel ("Facultad:");
    promedio = new JLabel ("Promedio:");
    intercambio = new JLabel ("Intercambio:");



    add(codigo);
    add(nombres);
    add(apellidos);
    add(semestreIngreso);
    add(facultad);
    add(promedio);
    add(intercambio);
}
```

codigo del panel derecho (constructor):

public InformacionEstudiante()
    {

```
    TitledBorder borde = (new TitledBorder("Derecha"));
    setBorder(borde);

    setLayout (new GridLayout (8,1));

    codigoT = new JTextField ("");
    codigoT.setEditable(false);


    nombresT = new JTextField ("");
    nombresT.setEditable(false);

    apellidosT = new JTextField ("");
    apellidosT.setEditable(false);

    semestreIngresoT = new JTextField ("");
    semestreIngresoT.setEditable(false);

    facultadT = new JTextField ("");
    facultadT.setEditable(false);

    promedioT = new JTextField ("");
    promedioT.setEditable(false);

    intercambioT = new JCheckBox ();


    cambiarPromedio = new JButton ("Cambiar Promedio");



    add(codigoT);

    add(nombresT);

    add(apellidosT);

    add(semestreIngresoT);

    add(facultadT);

    add(promedioT);

    add(intercambioT);


    add(cambiarPromedio);

}
```

Código del panel que hereda a los 2 anteriores (constructor):

public Cuerpo()
    {

```
    setLayout(new BorderLayout ());




    TitledBorder borde = BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Información estudiante");
    borde.setTitleColor(Color.black);
    setBorder(borde);

    imagen = new ImgEstudiante ();
    add (imagen, BorderLayout.WEST);

    informacionEstudianteLabel = new InformacionEstudianteLabel();
    add(informacionEstudianteLabel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    informacionEstudiante = new InformacionEstudiante ();
    add (informacionEstudiante, BorderLayout.EAST);




    navegacion = new Navegacion();
    add(navegacion, BorderLayout.SOUTH);





}
```

Comment: Por favor, añade el código que tengas con los paneles, para saber cómo lo tienes maquetado y dónde está el problema exactamente.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El BorderLayout está pensando para que el panel central ocupe lo máximo posible, respetando el tamaño que necesiten los paneles de los bordes.

Si quieres que el panel de la derecha se haga más ancho, el panel de la derecha tiene que "decir" de alguna forma que quiere ocupar más ancho del que realmente necesita.

En la clase InformacionEstudiante (creo que es el panel de la derecha), sobrescribe el método getPreferredSize() y/o getMinimumSize() para que devuelva el ancho que necesites.

Saludos.

Comment: Genial, muchas gracias.

Comment: Quisiera preguntarte una cosa. ¿Como quito el borde blanco arriba de la imagen del banner?

Comment: Depende de quién ponga ese borde. Puede estar como "padding" en el layout que uses del panel que tiene el banner, o pude ser parte del BorderLayout de la ventana padre.  Mira los layouts que estés usando y sus opciones de padding, para poner el superior a cero. Prueba también a poner "EmptyBorder" en los JPanel.