# Maximixar | Restaurar JPanel y JFrame

Tags: java, java-swing, netbeans-8.2

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación, en el JPanel principal tengo tres Layout.
El problema es cuando lo maximizo no se Maximizan todos los componentes de forma correcta quedan una parte que no se ajusta, entonces cual seria la forma indicada para que se ajustaran todos los componentes correctamente en el Jframe principal.
Normal:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Maximizado:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

necesitas usar un BorderPane o usar el BorderLayout para el panel que ya tienes, esto para poder agregar los componentes graficos dentro de este, y estos se adapten al ancho y alto de pantalla dado sin importar si la maximizas o no. Deberás tomar en cuenta la estructura del BorderLayout (arriba, abajo, derecha, centro, izquierda), te dejó el link de la documentación de Oracle respecto al layout y algunos links que te pueden ayudar a implementarlo. Saludos

*Para usar el BorderPane que trae el BorderLayout dentro:*
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/BorderPane.html

*Tutorial para usar el BorderLayout:
*https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/border.html

*Para que puedas redimensionar las zonas del BorderLayout a tu gusto:*
[Dimensiones de las zonas de un BorderLayout](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/71705/dimensiones-de-las-zonas-de-un-borderlayout)

**Buen diseño. Espero haberte sido de ayuda.**